# TinyMCE's isDirty method

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a card-making web project. I have a tinyMCE textfield and a visual of the card. Upon changing the content of the tinyMCE editor I want to update the visual of the card to reflect the new text/changes.

TinyMCE comes with an IsDirty method:

```
if (tinyMCE.activeEditor.isDirty())
    alert("You must save your contents.");
```

What I don't understand is WHERE I would place this if statement to regularly check for it. I understand that JS is event driven and so it needs to be "called", do I call it every keypress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a global timeout function that every second or so (the interval is up to you) checks:

```
function updateCardIfDirty() {
  if (tinyMCE.isDirty()) {
    // rerender the card
  }
}

setInterval(updateCardIfDirty, 2000); // check every 2 seconds.
```

A cleaner solution might be to check every time they make a change in the tinyMCE editor. This can be made possible by the `onChange()` event [tinyMCE provides](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3%3aevent.tinymce.Editor.onChange), as follows:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  ...
  setup : function(ed) {
     ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {
       // rerender the card
     });
  }
});
```

The downside of the first approach is that it will execute every 2 seconds, even if they dont edit the card for an hour. The downside of the second approach is that if they perform 10 edits in 1 second, it will rerender the card 10 times in that second.

So finally, let's try a third approach which gets the best of both worlds, and loses both disadvantages we mentioned:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  ...
  setup : function(ed) {
     ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {

       if (timeout) {
          clearTimeout(timeout);
       }

       timeout = setTimeout(function(){ timeout=null; rerenderCard(); }, 1000);

     });
  }
});
```

Comment: when using the "isdirty" method i couldn't get it to work, and the on-change doesn't update enough (you need to click off the editor or press Enter to get it to update.

Comment: your suggestions led me onto another idea though, so for that +1

Comment: @Daniel, you could of course use `OnKeyPress` or a mouse click event (or both) if `onChange` doesn't happen often enough, the same code shuold work

Comment: It was your first suggestion without the inner if statement that won it over for me, I'll accept your answer. I set the time interval to less than a second. Instant updating

Comment: The third solution is indeed the best IMHO, and it can be written in just one [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) function call, if you happen to be using LoDash or Underscore.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently trying to see how to fix TinyMCE in this regard. Outside of TinyMCE, the current cross browser solution is to use the OnTextChange DOM event that is supported by most of the current browsers. I test it today and it works really nice for non-keyboard right click cut/paste/delete and also keyboard changes.  No Keyboard events necessary with the textchange event. (Note, it needs to be prepared in DOM, google the jquery.textchange.js plugin).

However, it doesn't work when TinyMCE is wrapping the textarea control.  I am currently looking at the source and the plugins to see how to implement this textchange event.